# Internet Explorer 9 Display Issues

Tags: php, html, css, browser, internet-explorer-9

I am working on a website for a client. I have tested the website on Chrome, IE 10, IE 9 etc. But it seems on her computer the site does not display correctly (The logo overlaps the navigation text). She is using Windows Vista 32 Bit, Internet Explorer 9. She doesn't have compatibility mode on, and we have tried it with it on. Also cleared the cache and website data.

Under the link gallery, I had roll-over image/links which Dreamweaver automatically inserted the PHP script into the head of the html code. When I removed that, and just left the links the site went back to normal. I am a bit confused.

Link to the website can be found here (View source should display all the code etc):
http://astrodeer.com/clare/

Comment: Have you tried Chrome and Firefox on her machine to see if its exhibiting same symptoms. Also why not run Windows update to see if her machine is missing some important IE9 updates.

Comment: No I haven't, but I did check windows updates and their wasn't anything there. I'll get her to install chrome tonight and see how it goes.

Comment: That's a good place to start from. Some troubleshooting tips. Nice website :)

Comment: Fine in Chrome for her.

Comment: Good to hear that, so we have eliminated her computer as the culprit. So this is more of any issue with IE9 on her machine. Your client can do two things, either uninstall and re-install her IE9 and reapply all patches or upgrade to IE10.

Comment: There is no patches available through windows updates for IE9, Vista does not support IE10 sadly. The code posted below works well to stop the logo moving when the screen size is adjusted, but apparently she is still having problems. I have no idea why.

Comment: Tested it on my dads computer. Windows Xp, IE 8 works perfectly. Defiantly something with her version of IE 9 whether maybe it does need a patch or it needs to be re-installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for your CSS

```
#logo_container {
height: 50px;
margin-top: -20px;
width: 220px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
#logo_img {
height: 220px;
position: relative;
width: 220px;
z-index: 97;
}
#bridalgallery a {
background: #ffff00; /* use background:url(yourimage.png) */
padding: 10px;
display: block;
width:300px; /* use your image width */
height:300px; /* use your image heigth */
}
#bridalgallery a:hover {
background: #ffffff; /* use background:url(yourimagehover.png) */
padding: 10px;
display: block;
width:300px; /* use your image width */
height:300px; /* use your image heigth */
}
```